# How to disable checkboxes when when more than 6 checkboxes are selected?

Tags: visualforce, inputcheckboxes

Once the user selects 6 checkboxes I want all the other checkboxes to be disabled.How to do it?I tried adding a boolean variable for disabled attribute,It accepts exact 6.But it also disables all the checkboxes after that without allowing me to remove the selected checkbox also.

```
 <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!a.selected}" id="checkedone">

                                    <apex:actionSupport event="onclick" action="{!GetSelected}"
                                                        rerender="Selected_PBS,sizelimit" oncomplete="scrollPage()" status="loadStatus" >
                                        <apex:param name="accId" value="{!a.acc.id}"/>

                                    </apex:actionSupport>

                                </apex:inputCheckbox>
```

Comment: you can put a Javascript validation here

Comment: Thanks,@tushar.Is that with the limit?

Comment: check my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can put Jquery validation instead of taking apex route

```
$("input[name=chk]").change(function(){
    var max= 3;
    if( $("input[name=chk]:checked").length == max ){
        $("input[name=chk]").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        $("input[name=chk]:checked").removeAttr('disabled');
    }else{
         $("input[name=chk]").removeAttr('disabled');
    }
})
```

This will only allow you to check three checkbox you can change the limit.

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/48BvH/1/)

Or if you want a pure javascript solution then you can try this

```
function limit_checkbox(name,obj,max)
   {
   var count=0;
   var x=document.getElementsByName(name);
   for (var i=0; i < x.length; i++)
      {
      if(x[i].checked)
         {
         count = count + 1;
         }
      } 
   if (count > max)
      {
      alert('Please select only ' + max + ' checkboxes.\
To select this option unselect one of the others.');
      obj.checked = false;
      }
   }
```

[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4cvcb54s/)

Comment: This will work only for input type tag,right

Comment: @Pri you can use this with apex tag as well. Just need to modify few things as per your use case.

Answer (score 0):

Let The action fire. And inside Apex controller, check if you have already reached the size of 6.

If you have reached limit, make the checkbox variable false, so it will look uncheked on UI.

Additionally you can add apex pagemessages to inform user that he excced the select limit.

Comment: Thanks@Pranay Jaiswal,Doing so, is not removing the  initially selected 6 records.Everything gets disabled..If I want to remove that I should be able to do it..Because I am displaying the selected values below.

Comment: updated the description .Please have a look :)